# without x:Name="" to silverlight control gives assembly unknown namespace

Tags: silverlight, xaml, namespaces, xamlparseexception

I have a custom `ColorPicker` Control without giving `x:Name=""` to this control gives assembly unknown namespace error:

> The type 'ColorPicker' was not found because 'clr-namespace:SilverlightControls;assembly=SilverlightControls' is an unknown namespace..

Whereas it is working fine if I give it a name. Actually I have to use this Control in LisBox. I am using in this way:

```
xmlns:slColor="clr-namespace:SilverlightControls;assembly=SilverlightControls"

<slColor:ColorPicker  Height="23" Width="20" 
                      Color="{Binding PalleteColor, Mode=TwoWay}">
</slColor:ColorPicker>
```

Can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Color Picker too - and had this exact same problem.  One way to get around the x:Name problem is to stick it inside another **new** user control (**newControl**).  Inside the control's XAML, you can instantiate color picker, give it an `x:Name="myControl"`. Then in your repeating Listbox, you can have multiple instances of your **newControl**.
It seems silly, but nesting it just one level deep seems to solve the problem